# Email-to-Case issue

Tags: servicecloud, email2case

We have an Email-to-Case address called serviberia@iberia.es. While sending an email from clasica@iberia.es to serviberia@iberia.es, no Case is getting created.When we send an individual email to serviberia@iberia.es say from chetan@iberia.es, everything works fine.It's only when sending the email from clasica@iberia.es that nothing comes to Salesforce.
What could be the potential gotchas?How can we debug this?
Any immidiate help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the any exception is getting generated when you sent email from clasica@iberia.es? Also, check case validation rule if any restriction has been mentioned

Comment: No, No exception. When i include myself in CC, i receive the email but the email doesnot reach to salesforce email-to-case.